# jQuery change event not firing on page load, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code which is used in both purpose, even on click of any other button and even while editing, it should do on page load

Here is my code

```
$awaySelect = $('##awayID');

$awaySelect.change(function(){
      alert('hi'); 
      var awayData = $(this).val();
      if(awayData == 202 || awayData == 203){ 
            $('.gameToshowAway').show(); 
            $('.gameToshowAway').css('display','inline-block');
            $("##gameDate3").prop('disabled',false); 
            $('.gamedatecolor1').css('display','inline-block'); 
            $('.positionToDisplayAway').hide();                   
        } else {
            $('##unknownWell').hide();
            $('.gameToshowAway').hide();           
        } 

        if(awayData == 204) {
            $('.gameToshowAway').hide();  
            $('##unknownWell').hide();
            $('.positionToDisplayAway').css('display','inline-block');          
        }
    }).trigger();
```

but it not doing any alert even i had the trigger at the bottom to try to execute it on page load

what is wrong happening here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `.change()` with no arguments or pass the event name to `.trigger`.

```js
$awaySelect.change(function(e) {
    // ...
}).change();
// or
$awaySelect.trigger('change');
```